# CakePHP 3: FormHelper to load <label> after <input>?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is there any way to load `<label>` after `<input>`. By default CakePHP loads `<label>` before `<input>` like this:

Php Code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email', ['placeholder' => 'Email']); ?>
```

Generated Code:

```
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" type="email">
```

But what do I when I would like to get it like this:

```
<input name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" type="email">
<label for="email">Email</label>
```

Is there a way to have this besides hacking something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Templates

You can use the templating functionality, the template responsible for this is the `formGroup` one, which by default is `{{label}}{{input}}`.

```php
echo $this->Form->input('email', [
    'placeholder' => 'Email',
    'templates' => [
        'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}'
    ]
]);
```

It's also possible to define form group tempaltes per input type, by following the naming convention that is the name of the type, followed by `FormGroup`. So for the `email` type that would be `emailFormGroup`.

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, [
    'templates' => [
        'emailFormGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}',
        'textFormGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}'
        // ...
    ]
]);
```

That way you can easily apply this option globally to specific types only.

See also **[Cookbook > Form Helper > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**

### CSS

And of course you could also use CSS, there's tables

```css
.input.email {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.input.email input {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.input.email label {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
```

flex-box ordering

```css
.input.email {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.input.email input {
    order: 1;
}
.input.email label {
    order: 2;
}
```

etc...

Comment: Templating `formGroup` was exactly what I was looking for.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [label()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-labels) method of the `FormHelper`, like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('email', ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'label' => false]);
echo $this->Form->label('email', 'Email');
?>
```

Comment: Yeah. I did not want to take that approach because I wanted `input` to handle it as I have a `<div>` that wraps them together and that comes from setting up `form templates for inputContainer`. I just wished there was an `option` that I could activate like `after` or `before` on the `label` option that would activate where `<label>` should be placed. Anyway, I will give that a try....

Comment: I don't know what are you looking exactly, but if you only need to _see_ the input before the label, maybe you can do that with css.

Comment: I will take the approach you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach is to create a Custom helper and overwrite the existing one using the way @Choma suggested.

So you will have to add in your

```
//View/Helpers/MyCustomFormHelper.php

App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');

MyCustomFormHelper extends FormHelper{

    public function input($fieldName, $options) {
        $defaults = array_merge($options, array('label' => false))
        echo parent::input($fieldName, $defaults);
        echo parent::label(fieldName);
    }
}

//AppController.php

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array(
        'Form' => array(
            'className' => 'MyCustomFormHelper'
         )
    );
}
```

Or you could use the after option and for doing it more easy again inside your own helper.

```
//View/Helpers/MyCustomFormHelper.php

App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');

MyCustomFormHelper extends FormHelper{

    public function input($fieldName, $options) {
        $after = parent::label(fieldName);
        $defaults = array_merge($options, array(
            'label' => false,
            'after' =>  $after,
        ));
        return parent::input($fieldName, $defaults);
    }

    //or do not overwrite the input function and use a custom one
    public function inputLabelAfter($fieldName, $options) {
    ...
    ...
    }

}
```

I am sorry if the code has errors I haven't tested it but I think you got the picture and gave you more ideas.

Edit: I hadn't seen that this is for CakePHP 3.x. The above example is for 2.x but I believe that it will do.

Comment: I had started creating a `FormEx` but did not approach it that way. I will certainly takes this and try it out.. thanks. I will post back

Answer (score 0):

Using templates is the right way to go - I hope this helps...

```
 $this->Form->templates([
        'nestingLabel' => '{{input}}<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
        'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}',
 ]);
```

[Moving Checkboxes & Radios Outside of a Label](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#moving-checkboxes-radios-outside-of-a-label)